# How can I use a div that has css styles with browser prefix in the name in a toggleClass?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, toggleclass

I am using the following solution to work with some cross browser issues I was having:

[Cross Browser Fix](http://rafael.adm.br/css_browser_selector/)

In my CSS, using the above solution, I have something like:

```
 .some_class {
      margin-left: 40px;
 }
 .win.ie some_class {
      margin-left: 100px;
 }
```

The win.ie some_class gets used only on Windows for IE only.

Now, elsewhere in my code using JavaScript I am using the following:

```
    $("#someid").toggleClass("some_class");
```

What I need to do now is to use .win.ie some_class in the above JS snippet.  How can I do it?

I tried doing:

```
 $("#someid").toggleClass(".win.ie some_class");
```

But that simply adds that to the actual class in HTML.  Is it possible to accomplish what I am trying to do here?

Comment: As a general rule, if you need 60 pixels extra margin in IE for Windows only, your doing something seriously wrong in the markup? As a sidenote, the plugin you are referencing was released in 2006.

Comment: @adeneo, I just used the above css stuff as an example.  I realize it's from 2006 but it works fine for the projects I have used them on.

Comment: Even if the code works, using code that is that old, and especially for browser sniffing (which you should'nt really do at all), will cause you nothing but problems, but do whatever you like ?

Answer (score 1):

This is not valid CSS:

```
.win.ie some_class {
      margin-left: 100px;
 }
```

Try this:

```
.win.ie.some_class
```

Which will apply styles to elements with the `win`, `ie`, and `some_class` classes. Or:

```
.win.ie .some_class
```

If the `some_class` element is a child of an element with the `win` and `ie` classes.

Comment: Thanks.  But in the link I posted above, that's how they have it.

Comment: That is not true. Only plain html elements like `div` or `header` can be used a selectors without being preceded by a `.` for classes or `#` for divs.

Comment: They seem to be working for me.  It's just this one where I can't make sense of it.

Answer (score 0):

First, let's fix the CSS, the some_class is missing the dot:

```
.win.ie .some_class {
    margin-left: 100px;
}
```

Second, scope the find on the toggleClass instead of the actual class:

```
$(".win.ie #someid").toggleClass("some_class");
```